# glDrawElements draws nothing

Tags: opengl

As the title says…. :( nothing is drawn on screen… is there something I'm missing?

```
Mesh *Mesh_Create(GLfloat vertices[], GLuint indices[], GLfloat uvs[], GLfloat colors[])
{


Mesh *mesh = (Mesh*)malloc(sizeof(Mesh));


mesh->vertices = (GLfloat*)malloc(sizeof(vertices));
memcpy(mesh->vertices, vertices, sizeof(vertices));

mesh->indices = (GLuint*)malloc(sizeof(indices));
memcpy(mesh->indices, indices, sizeof(indices));

mesh->elementCount = sizeof(indices) / sizeof(GLuint);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &mesh->vao);
glBindVertexArray(mesh->vao);

glGenBuffers(1, &mesh->vbo[VERTEXBUFFER]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->vbo[VERTEXBUFFER]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(mesh->vertices), &mesh->vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

/*glGenBuffers(1, &mesh->vbo[TEXTUREBUFFER]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->vbo[TEXTUREBUFFER]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(uvs), uvs, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
*/
glGenBuffers(1, &mesh->vbo[INDICESBUFFER]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->vbo[INDICESBUFFER]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(mesh->indices), &mesh->indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

/*glGenBuffers(1, &mesh->vbo[COLORBUFFER]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->vbo[COLORBUFFER]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(colors), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);*/

/*glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);*/


return mesh;
}

Mesh *Mesh_CreateQuad()
{

GLfloat vertices[] = { -0.5,  -0.5,
                        0.5,  -0.5,
                        0.5,   0.5,
                       -0.5,   0.5 };

GLuint indices[] = { 0,1,2,
                      0,2,3 };

GLfloat uvs[] = {   0 , 1,
                    1,  1,
                    1,  0,
                    0,  0 };

GLfloat colors[] = {    1, 1, 1, 1,
                        1, 1, 1, 1,
                        1, 1, 1, 1,
                        1, 1, 1, 1 };

return Mesh_Create(vertices, indices, uvs, colors);
}

void Mesh_Render(Mesh *mesh)
{
    glBindVertexArray(mesh->vao);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh->elementCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &mesh->indices);
}
```

Comment: What are  your  model, view, and projection matrices set to?

Comment: I've added it now…. please help

Comment: Hi and welcome to gamedev! You might want to include just the code you think it's relevant to your question, instead of providing a whole lot of code that we need to read and test. Also, do you have some sort of way to debug opengl? One example would be to call `glGetError()` or to use tools like `RenderDoc`.

Comment: Please don't change your code after you received an answer! It will confuse future readers. Instead, if you really want to post fixed code, post it as an answer.

Comment: yeah… Sorry… Just one thing! I'm having problems with memcpy…

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you're unbinding:

```
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Because your VAO is still active when you unbind, you're actually setting the bindings stored in the VAO to 0 when you do this.

**So your VAO has 0 bound to GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER meaning that no element array buffer will be used during your glDrawElements call** - the actual outcome of which will vary depending on whether you use a core profile (GL_INVALID_OPERATION will be generated) or not (you might get no output, you might get garbage output, you might get a random crash).

---

Your element array buffer setup also makes no sense:

```
    glGenBuffers(1, &mesh->vbo[INDICESBUFFER]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->vbo[INDICESBUFFER]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices) * sizeof(GLubyte), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, false, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

There's no need to use either glVertexAttribPointer or glEnableVertexAttribArray here, and in fact vertex attrib pointer setup only latches the most recently bound GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, so these pointers will in fact use your mesh->vbo[TEXTUREBUFFER].

That shouldn't affect the glDrawElements call working or not, however, although - depending on your vertex shader - the output might not be what you expect.

---

Finally...

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh->elementCount, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mesh->indices);
```

Where:

```
mesh->indices = (GLubyte*)malloc(sizeof(indices));
mesh->indices = indices;
```

And:

```
GLubyte indices[] = { 0,1,2,
                      0,2,3 };
```

There are lots of things wrong with this.

First of all, "indices" is a local variable declared on the stack, meaning that it will go out of scope when Mesh_CreateQuad exits, meaning that it will just contain stack garbage any future time you might reference that memory location.

So then you malloc mesh->indices, but "mesh->indices = indices" **doesn't copy the data**; it just copies the pointer assignment.  In other words, "*the memory location pointed to mesh->indices is set to be the memory location pointed to by indices*".  But, as we've seen, *the memory location pointed to by indices* will go out of scope and potentially contain random garbage, so mesh->indices **likewise contains random garbage** *after indices goes out of scope*.

This is obviously all wrong, and you really need to work a lot on your understanding of memory management and pointers in C/C++ here.

---

And one last note is that you really shouldn't use GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE with glDrawElements because it's unlikely to be hardware accelerated.  So even though it might be appealing because it saves memory, it will actually run slower than using a larger type.

---

So, in summary:

- Set up your ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER correctly.
- Copy memory correctly using memcpy instead of just copying pointer assignments.
- Always draw from buffer objects if using a core profile; this includes both your ARRAY_BUFFER(s) and your ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER.
- If you unbind your ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER while a VAO is bound, you'll unbind it from that VAO and that VAO will be unable to draw with indices.  This applies even if you do everything else correctly - **unbinding is evil** - don't do it, even if it's what a tutorial teaches (it's a bad tutorial if it unbinds).

Comment: Yes I'm getting random crashed…. I'm not interested in CORE.
This is a simple 2D app.
but yeah I've changed it but still... nothing is drawn…
You can see on top

Comment: IIRC, VBO binding is not a part of VAO state. It's a part of global state. VAO remembers currently bound VBO when you call `glVertexAttribPointer`, you can safely unbind your VBO after that.

Comment: You can unbind GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, you can't unbind GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER.

Answer (score 0):

Something is appearing but not working entirely. Can someone help?

```
Mesh *Mesh_Create(GLfloat vertices[], unsigned int vertexElements, GLuint indices[], unsigned int indexElements, GLfloat uvs[], unsigned int uvElements, GLfloat colors[], unsigned int colorElements)
{
    Mesh *mesh = (Mesh*)malloc(sizeof(Mesh));

    mesh->vertices = (GLfloat*)malloc(sizeof(GLfloat) * vertexElements);
    memcpy(mesh->vertices, vertices, sizeof(GLfloat) * vertexElements);

    mesh->uvs = (GLfloat*)malloc(sizeof(GLfloat) * uvElements);
    memcpy(mesh->uvs, uvs, sizeof(GLfloat) * uvElements);

    mesh->indices = (GLuint*)malloc(sizeof(GLuint) * indexElements);
    memcpy(mesh->indices, indices, sizeof(GLuint) * indexElements);

    mesh->elementCount = vertexElements * 3;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &mesh->vao);
    glBindVertexArray(mesh->vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &mesh->vbo[VERTEXBUFFER]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->vbo[VERTEXBUFFER]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * vertexElements, &mesh->vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &mesh->vbo[TEXTUREBUFFER]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->vbo[TEXTUREBUFFER]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * uvElements, &mesh->uvs, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glGenBuffers(1, &mesh->vbo[INDICESBUFFER]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->vbo[INDICESBUFFER]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint) * indexElements, &mesh->indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    /*glGenBuffers(1, &mesh->vbo[COLORBUFFER]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->vbo[COLORBUFFER]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * colorElements, &mesh->colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);*/

    return mesh;
}

Mesh *Mesh_CreateQuad()
{
    GLfloat vertices[8] = { -0.5,  -0.5,//   0,
                              0.5,  -0.5,//   0,
                              0.5,   0.5,//   0,
                             -0.5,   0.5 };//,   0 };

    GLuint indices[6] = { 0,1,2,
                          0,2,3 };

    GLfloat uvs[8] = {  0 , 1,
                        1,  1,
                        1,  0,
                        0,  0 };

    GLfloat colors[16] = {  1, 1, 1, 1,
                            1, 1, 1, 1,
                            1, 1, 1, 1,
                            1, 1, 1, 1 };

    return Mesh_Create(vertices, 8, indices, 6, uvs, 8, colors, 16);
}

void Mesh_Render(Mesh *mesh)
{
    glBindVertexArray(mesh->vao);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh->elementCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If this didn't solve your problem, do not post it as an Answer. Use the edit link to add it as a further detail in your Question.